# Error: "invalid type for comparison" in revel template

Tags: templates, go, revel

After creating multple endpoints customizing footer.html, I end up with this error for not apparent this don't effect the functionally of the application, just annoying me. 
 Tried:

```
  revel run revel_app or dev
```

Revel Template Execution Error

: executing "footer.html" at : error calling eq: invalid type for comparison.

```
  {{if eq .RunMode "dev"}}

  {{template "debug.html" .}}

  {{end}}
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the whole `footer` template code? Also just before executing the template can you log the contents of `c.ViewArgs` and ensure that `"RunMode"` is present and that its a `string`.

Comment: All the footer code is already added. And yes it's a string.

Comment: Can you show what you're passing to `c.Render`? And also can you show what `c.ViewArgs` contains just before calling render and after?

Comment: Also I assume footer is a "partial" template called from another template like `{{template "footer.html" .something}}`, correct? If that's the case then make sure that `something` contains `"RunMode"` and that it's a `string`.

Comment: I have couple of them. sharing all of it. here 
                                                                                                         
  return c.Render(ts) ,  return c.Render(&models.Lists{})
 Will give it a try. Am I asking a right question?

Comment: That worked thank can you add a answer so I can vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you see arises when one of the arguments to `eq` is either undefined in the current context or is not of a "basic type" ([see the last paragraph of this section](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions))

So assuming that `footer.html` is a "pratial" template that is associated with other templates which invoke the footer template using the *template action* you need to ensure that the context passed in to the template invocation contains the `.RunMode` value and that the value is of a *basic type*.

Comment: answer explains why but does not provide a way around. This problem gets wonky when comparing untyped dot values.

Comment: @Richard If you read the comments you'll see that my, according to you, insufficient explanation, resolved the issue OP was having, which leads me to believe that your issue is probably different and you should create a new question if you're looking for help.

Answer (score 4):

While this question seems to be answered there is plenty missing. First the question is incomplete... WHAT IS THE ERROR?  My guess us that the `.RunMode` is missing when the template parser/executor was run. There are not best practices for golang templates, however, this is a common problem when overloading templates and not maintaining a dictionary of variables.

One strategy I tend to deploy is:

```
{{if eq (or .RunMode "default") "dev"}}
```

This way if `.RunMode` is NOT assigned a value (nil exception) or an empty string then the `eq` uses the `"default"` value instead. Think of this as a shorthand like in 'C'

This is an exaggerated example.

```
a := runmode!=null?runmode:default
```

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing "string" with a variable `.RunMode` of some unknown type. How about casting that variable to string ?

`{{if eq (.RunMode | toString) "dev"}}`

Comment: That was my case. Not sure why helm did not get actual string as.. string from .Values. Thank you!